# Tabris 1.3.0 - closeCurrentPage() throws error, how when to use?

Tags: tabris

Probably a very stupid question from a new bee. I'm looking for a solution to navigation back from a page, not by pressing a navigation button, but from code. So in my case by selecting a table row, I open its detail page:

page.openPage(DetailsPage.class.getName());

This DetailsPage has a delete button that triggers some functionality and requires to close the page at the end of all the delete actions.

When using closeCurrentPage() on this DetailsPage I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not close top level page.

What is the proper way to close a page/ navigate back to the parent?

Thanks!
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experience with Tabris, but I will try to help.

First of all, check if DetailsPage should be configured as a top level page.

If this is indeed your intention then you cannot close this page (because it is an top level page).
To open previous page you need to implement this on your own.
For example:
  opening details page

```
            PageData data = new PageData();
            data.set( "previousId", getUI().getPageOperator().getCurrentPageId() );
            data.set( "previousData", getUI().getPageOperator().getCurrentPageData() );
            page.openPage( DetailsPage.class.getName(), data );
```

Opening previous page from details page

```
            openPage(getData().get( "previousId", String.class ),
                     getData().get( "previousData", PageData.class ) );
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As mferlan pointed out, top level pages can't be closed. This document may help understanding why: http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/1.3/working/tabris-ui/

Comment: Thanks! Of course, why reading the manual right? Thanks for pointing out, had indeed different top levels due to copy and paste and not realizing the impact.